# Saving a Multidimensional to Database

Tags: yii

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => today
            [1] => today
        )

    [grp] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

How I can save this into a table in yii. name, age and grp can have unlimited number of values.

table id, name, age and grp

Comment: We're going to need a little more to go on than that. Try posting the schema for the tables involved and we can go from there.

Comment: My table have id, name, age and grp fields.

Comment: @AdarshPv: Are you using `ActiveRecord`? Do you have a model for this table?

Comment: OK You need to update your question with the structure of any tables this involves, and how the data should be linked together. e.g. Why you can't just put in a row for each element of the array.

Answer (score 4):

if each array index is new record in your db , you can use this in your controller:

```
$lenth = count($yourArray['name']); // this line will return the count of records must be inserted to db table
for( $i = 0 ; $i < $lenth ; $i++ )
{
    $newRecord = new ModelName;
    $newRecord->name = $yourArray['name'][$i];
    $newRecord->age = $yourArray['age'][$i];
    $newRecord->grp = $yourArray['grp'][$i];
    $newRecord->save();
}
```